# Armstrong Numbers using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is not a question, but more of a public help... I was given an assignment to find the Armstrong Numbers within 100 (there are only 0 and 1) as an assignment. I searched the internet to find such a program, but none. Methods for arrays and some other stuff were only available and I didn't have time for asking help and getting the script done... So, here I give you the JavaScript program for finding Armstrong Numbers... I know that the method is redundant, and if you have a better idea in mind, please share...

Thank you.

```js
var a = [];

var b = new Array();

for (var ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
    b[ii] = new Array(1001);

    for (var j = 0; j < 1001; j++) {
        a[j] = 0;
        b[ii][j] = 0;
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < 1001; i++) {
    a[i] = i;
    b[0][i] = a[i] % 10;
    b[1][i] = Math.floor(i / 10);
    b[1][i] = b[1][i] % 10;
    b[2][i] = Math.floor(i / 100);
    b[2][i] = b[2][i] % 10;

    if (i === Math.pow(b[0][i], 3) +
              Math.pow(b[1][i], 3) +
              Math.pow(b[2][i], 3)) {
        console.log(i + " is an armstrong number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not only okay, but *encouraged*, to answer your own question, but there are some problems to fix here: 1. The question should contain only the *question* (concisely, we don't need to know that you couldn't find a solution elsewhere on the 'net); the *answer* should go in an *answer*. 2. Indent your code readably. 3. Explain what's going on in the code; code dumps aren't useful. Please do take the [tour] and look through the [help] to get an idea how things are done here. You can use the "edit" link under your question to edit, and the "Post your answer" button below to answer it.

Comment: And thanks for contributing!